# Buck-boost Von and Voff calculations

Tags: inductor, kirchhoffs-laws

Regarding the A to Z switching power supply book,I calculated the Voff equation which is against the book's calculation.
[image]
[image]
My KVL for Von mode:
$$-Vin+Vsw+Von=0 => Von=Vin-Vsw$$
which confirms the book calculation.However,
My KVL for Voff mode:
(I know that the inductor tries to suppress any current changes with reversed spike voltage but for solving the mathematical forms of inductor voltage we assume the voltage polarity is the same before and after switching and write the KVL([enter link description here](https://www.ee.nthu.edu.tw/%7Esdyang/Courses/Circuits/Ch07_Std.pdf)). In addition, Vd is diode voltage with is always is positive)
$$-Voff-Vd-Vo=0=>Voff=-Vd-Vo$$
If the writer assumed that the polarity is changed, I need to obtain it mathematically. (for example in a situation that is not easy to say that the polarity is changed or not)
which is not similar to the book result. I thought maybe the book assume the sign of Vo is opposite of the capacitor voltage so I changed it to:
$$-Voff-Vd+Vo=0=>Voff=Vo-Vd$$
if I assume the polarity of the inductor being changed in off mode, it would be correct but based on my academic knowledge after switching mode the polarite of the capacitor and inductor should be assumed the same before and after switching status.

On the next page of the book the diagram it shows the correct form:
$$-(Vd+Vo)$$
[image]
But why for obtaining the duty we should assume it positive that we know the reversed voltage polarity.
what is my mistake?

Comment: Voff has to be more negative than Vo in order to forward bias the diode during the off cycle. Or put another way, Vo has to be more positive than Voff in order to forward bias the diode during the off cycle. Pretty basic. I don't have the book, unfortunately, so I can't comment much about the equations since I don't know, for example, if Vd is always a positive value or if its sign changes depending on the phase, Voff vs Von. I'm confused. Maybe someone else has the book and can straighten you out. I will just watch, I suppose.

Comment: You remembered wrong. In the inductor, the current wants to flow in the same direction as in the T_ON cycle. So to be able to do it the voltage across the inductor must change polarity to the opposite polarity that we have during T_ON.  And V_off = VD +VO because the author is using the absolute values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have edited my main post to clear my questions very well.

Comment: I still do not get what your problem is. The author is using absolute values. Ths author cares only about the magnitude of a number, not the number sign.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation, if the author calculated $$Voff = VD +VO$$ why on the diagram and based on my calculation it mentions $$Voff =-( VD +VO)$$. it uses the  $$Voff = VD +VO$$ for calculating the duty cycle but for waveform he accepted my derived equation.

Comment: Because Buck-Boost is an inverting topology. So D = Vo / (Vo - Vi) = (-10V) / ((- 10) - 10V) = 0.5 is the same as if we used absolute values D = Vo / (Vo + Vi) = 10V / (10 + 10V) = 0.5

Comment: I appreciate your useful answer.